# Pine allergies is it possible?

Tags: seasonal-allergies

Just a late Christmas question, is it possible to be allergic to pine trees?(aka Christmas trees) I’m asking for curiosities sake mostly.

Comment: You can be allergic to almost anything, especially organic things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a neighbor (who actually farmed Christmas trees) who was allergic to pine pollen. That's not something that you would get from bringing a tree into the house in December though. You can find plenty of information about pine tree pollen allergies - [they don't appear to be serious](https://www.pollen.com/research/genus/pinus).

The American College of Asthma, Allergy, and Immunology [points out](http://acaai.org/allergies/types/allergy-myths/pine-tree-allergy) that some people are also allergic to eating pine nuts. Keep that in mind, though cones on your tree shouldn't be considered edible anyway, the tree may have been sprayed with all kinds of things.

Finally, not all Christmas trees are pine.